# using a RProfile.site

Tags: r

I have several computers running R and share scripts on Dropbox. Since my Dropbox folder is located differently on different computers, I have to set different working directories up.

I have put the code to identify which of my computers I am using in the RProfile.site

```
if(Sys.info()[4]=="DESKTOP-VEGO337") { 
  main.dir <- 'E:/Users/nn/Dropbox/R'
  setwd(main.dir)
} 
else if(Sys.info()[4]=="Mac.local") {
main.dir <- 'H:/Users/nn/Dropbox/R'
  setwd(main.dir)
}
```

However everytime I update my computer I have to manually update all my computers RProfile.site's. Hence I would like to have my RProfile.site in my dropbrox folder so I only shall manage one file which will be general for all my computers.

Is it possible to place RProfile.site outside the R/R3.4.1/etc folder?

And if How do I reference it to my windows version

Comment: No. But you could use a normal .Rprofile instead?

Comment: I am not fully sure I fully understand the .Rprofile. For what I have googled it seems like a RProfile.site just placed in the R working folder. But how does my R know where the workin folder is located, if not specified in RProfile.site?

Comment: I tried to copy my RProfile.site as a .RProfile in my R root Dropbox folder. It worked when I started my R, but as soon I am running a script, it seems that the .Rprofile is forgotten. (Iis not global for my environment)